# Cheerio `text()` empty string for span tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I've loaded to Cheerio [a product from belk.com](http://www.belk.com/AST/Main/Belk_Primary/PRD~8100331SIGNA8328T4/Le+Creuset+Signature+5+qt++Oval+French+Oven.jsp).
I can get to the price element using the selector `[class="price"]`, but when I try to get its text using `text()`, I get an empty string.

If I do `$('class="price"').contents()` I can see a child with the text, but it seems like the wrong way to go. Is there a generic method to getting the element text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That HTML has both `p` and `span` tags with class `price`, so you'll need to be more specific. This works for me `$('p.price span.price').text()`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is expected `node` REPL behavior.

The values tested negative for null and in debugger mode I could see the scraped value from Cheerio. Because it contained `\r` characters, printing it to console looked as if it's an empty string.